# React.js: set parent title from child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing a website with React/Redux and I use `react-router`. I would like to set the title of the parent component from the child pages.

```
const App = ({ title, children }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {children}
  </div>
);

const Page1 = () => (
  <p>Content Page 1</p>
);

const Page2 = () => (
  <p>Content Page 1</p>
);
```

I looked at `DocumentTitle`, but that is not what I am looking for.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to turn the parent component (`App`) into a class component rather than a stateless component, because `title` will become part of its state.  You then have a `setTitle` function within the parent, which is passed as a prop to the children.  In order to pass an additional prop to children, we need to use `React.cloneElement` - I have also used `React.children.map` which is not necessary if there is only ever going to be one child component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            title: 'Default Title'
        }
        this.setTitle = this.setTitle.bind(this);
    }

    setTitle(newTitle) {
        this.setState({
            title: newTitle
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => 
                    React.cloneElement(child, { setParentTitle: this.setTitle })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Page1 = ({ setParentTitle }) => {
    setParentTitle('Page 1');
    return (
        <p> Content Page 1</p>
    );
};
```